# Loop for in JointJs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jointjs

How to use loop for in `joint.shapes.uml`. I don't know can or can't use it.

```
var uml = joint.shapes.uml;
    var classes = {
            @Model.Entity[0]: new uml.Class({
                position: { x: 30, y: 40 },
                size: { width: 200, height: 220 },

                name: '@Model.Entity[0]',
                attributes: ['@Model.Column'],
                methods: [],
                attrs: {
                    '.uml-class-name-rect': {
                        fill: 'white',
                        stroke: 'black',
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                    },
                    '.uml-class-attrs-rect, .uml-class-methods-rect': {
                        fill: 'white',
                        stroke: 'black',
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                    },
                }
            }),

            @Model.Entity[1]: new uml.Class({
                position: { x: 624, y: 103 },
                size: { width: 200, height: 150 },
                name: '@Model.Entity[1]',
                attributes: ['DeptName', '...', 'Etc.'],
                methods: [],
                attrs: {
                    '.uml-class-name-rect': {
                        fill: 'white',
                        stroke: 'black',
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                    },
                    '.uml-class-attrs-rect, .uml-class-methods-rect': {
                        fill: 'white',
                        stroke: 'black',
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                    },
                },
            })
        };

        graph.addCells(classes);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I finish loop for already.

```
var prepareDesign = function(designItems, connectors){
        $.each(designItems, function( index, value ) {
            addDesignItem(value);
        });
        $.each(connectors, function( index, value ) {
            addConnector(value);
        });
    }
    var connectors = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Relationship));
    var designItems = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Entity));
    prepareDesign(designItems, connectors);
```